# Creating multiple audio file form a single Txt file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to create multiple mp3 files based on one existing txt file. the txt file is separated by paragraphs. i have figured out to use gTTS to convert the text to audio but i'm having trouble with splitting the txt file.

single txt file:

```
[Hello Jay
Hello Tom]
```

I want to have two different audio file. one that says "Hello Jay" and another that says "Hello Tom"

I'm really new to python and i only managed to convert the txt file into audio at this point.

```
from gtts import gTTS

with open("1_3.txt", encoding = "utf-8") as file:
    file = file.read()

speak = gTTS(file, lang= "en")
speak.save("1_3.mp3")
```

Only managed to create one audio file that says both "Hello Jay Hello Tom"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are reading the whole file in one go, and then running the synthesizer on the entire text. You want to loop over the lines, and create one MP3 file for each line.

```py
from gtts import gTTS

with open("1_3.txt", encoding = "utf-8") as lines:
    for index, line in enumerate(lines, 1):
        speak = gTTS(line, lang= "en")
        speak.save("1_3_{0}.mp3".format(index))
```

The `enumerate` wrapper is used to increment a number for each line. We use that to create a unique name for each output file.  So the first line ends up in `1_3_1.mp3`, the second, in `1_3_2.mp3`, and so forth.

Comment: What should i do if i have multiple lines? 
E.g.
[Hello jay
Hello tom
hello kat
...]
so on and so forth

Comment: What do you mean? That's exactly what you asked in the question, and exactly the question I am answering. This generates one MP3 file per line of text, regardless of how many lines there are (though your file system will probably set a limit eventually if you have thousands or millions of input lines).

Comment: The square brackets only add confusion; I guess they are not actually part of the text. And the lesson here is to mention in the question if you actually need more than exactly two in the first place, rather than pile on additional requirements after you have received an answer.

Comment: apologies for the square brackets. i ran into an issue with your answer.
only 1 audio file was created based on the first paragraph
AssertionError: No text to send to TTS API

Comment: I'm guessing you have empty lines in your real input file. Maybe accept this answer (or post an answer of your own and accept that if you prefer) and ask a new question with a proper [mre].